# Discover/Around endpoint returns only 100 results max, how to get next page

Tags: here-api

I'm using the HERE-API's around endpoint doc'd here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-around.html

I'm specifying the size to be 1000 yet it only returns 100 results, but I do not see a next page token or anything like that to get the rest of the results.  (I can quarantee there are more than 100 results)

Answer (score 0):

The Here API has a hard bound of 100 results and there is no pagination. You can restrict your search based on categories or trigger another query for a point nearby to get another 100 results.

Comment: Does this still apply in 2019 to the Discover and Search API endpoint?